# Spring batch JpaPagingItemReader (possibly) removes rows from the database while using SELECT native query

Tags: mysql, spring, groovy, orm, spring-batch

I'm trying to perform a native SELECT query with JpaPagingItemReader. However, when i run it, some records are deleted from my database (I checked it before and after the batch job execution with mysql console). The one and only place where I communicate with the MySQL database is when I read the data - like this:

```
@Autowired
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory

@Value('${integration.date.value}')
String date


@Bean
JpaPagingItemReader<Entry> entryJpaPagingItemReader() {
    JpaPagingItemReader jpaPagingItemReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Entry>()
    jpaPagingItemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
    jpaPagingItemReader.setQueryProvider(createQueryProvider())
    jpaPagingItemReader.setPageSize(500)
    jpaPagingItemReader.afterPropertiesSet()
    jpaPagingItemReader
}

private JpaNativeQueryProvider<Entry> createQueryProvider() {
    String query = "SELECT distinct * FROM entry e WHERE e.entry_formal_category in ('FIL','SER') " +
            "and e.entry_categories not regexp 'DZI|INN|DOK' and e.entry_date = \'" + date + "\'" +
            " GROUP BY e.entry_title ORDER BY e.entry_id"

    JpaNativeQueryProvider<Entry> queryProvider = new JpaNativeQueryProvider<Entry>()
    queryProvider.setSqlQuery(query)
    queryProvider.setEntityClass(Entry)
    queryProvider.afterPropertiesSet()
    queryProvider
}
```

I'm quite shocked about this behavior - each time i execute the job i loose about 10 to 50 records from the database. Is it possible that the problem is caused by paging the native query results?

EDIT: a little update. When I set the pageSize to 1500 (it is a size, that will hold all rows on one page) the problem doesn't occur. It looks that it may be a spring-batch bug.

Comment: What happens after the read? Maybe you use the orm objects in a way, which makes the ORM Layer behave this way

Comment: Ok - i have missed one place where I modified an Entry object and the changes propagated to the database before fetching another page. Spring batch works perfectly well - it was my fault. Thank you! :)

Comment: @leśnik Could you please add same as answer instead of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - i have missed one place where I modified an Entry object and the changes propagated to the database before fetching another page. Spring batch works perfectly well - it was my fault. Problem solved - thank you! :)